# Sed in not honoring the $ address char when i try to only match last occurrence from within a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

**NOTE: I asked this question on stack exchange as well b/c I was having issues editing this post. Luckily I got an answer there:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546208/sed-in-not-honoring-the-address-char-when-i-try-to-only-match-last-occurrence?noredirect=1#comment1013405_546208

^^^ SEE LINK ABOVE FOR SOLUTION THAT I FOUND THAT WORKED FOR ME ^^^

I have created a simple script that I want to use to rename files based on a pattern.

The script uses find and sed to do its work,

Everything is basically working, except when I use the $ to tell sed to only match the last occurrence, it fails to match anything.

If I remove the $ all occurrences are matched, so that works, but I specifically want to target only the last occurrence.
Example:
    sed "s/${search}/${replace}/g" # Finds matches
    sed "s/${search}$/${replace}/g" # Does not find matches

I've simplified the code below, the searchReplaceLastMatchOnly() function demonstrates what i am trying to do with sed that does not work.

The searchReplace() function shows how the sed pattern does find matches if the $ address is not used.

My test directory is as follows:
./bar
./bar/baz
./bar/foobar.txt
./bar/baz/foobar.txt

```
# Search and replace using command: sed "s/${search}/${replace}/g")"
# This works, but is not what i want, i just need last occurence.
function searchReplace() {
    # spaces are set as defaults
    target=${1:- }
    search=${2:- }
    replace=${3:- }
    result="$(printf "%s" "$target" | sed "s/${search}/${replace}/g")"
    printf "%s" "$result"
}

# Search and replace using command: sed "s/${search}$/${replace}/g")"
# This is what I have read should work, using $ should only match
# last occurence, this is what I want but it does not work.
function searchReplaceLastMatchOnly() {
    # spaces are set as defaults
    target=${1:- }
    search=${2:- }
    replace=${3:- }
    ### sed NOT WORKING WITH $ ###
    result="$(printf "%s" "$target" | sed "s/${search}$/${replace}/g")"
    printf "%s" "$result"
}

# demo
search="bar"
replace="Bar"
dirPath="."
pattern="*.txt"
printf "\n"
find "$dirPath" -type f -name "$pattern" | while IFS= read -r original; do
    modified="$(searchReplaceLastMatchOnly "$original" "$search" "$replace")"
    printf "\nRenaming %s to %s\n" "$original" "$modified"
    #mv "$original" "$modified"
done
printf "\n"

# Currently this has following results:
#
# Renaming ./bar/baz/foobar.txt to ./bar/baz/foobar.txt
#
# Renaming ./bar/foobar.txt to ./bar/foobar.txt
#

printf "\n"
find "$dirPath" -type f -name "$pattern" | while IFS= read -r original; do
    modified="$(searchReplace "$original" "$search" "$replace")"
    printf "\nRenaming %s to %s\n" "$original" "$modified"
    #mv "$original" "$modified"
done
printf "\n"

# Currently this has following results:
#
# Renaming ./bar/baz/foobar.txt to ./Bar/baz/fooBar.txt
#
# Renaming ./bar/foobar.txt to ./Bar/fooBar.txt
```

Comment: So what is the actual `sed` command you use, or at least one that reproduces the problem?

Comment: please review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); in particular, please edit (or re-post your question) with a) sample data being fed to `sed`, b) your `sed` command(s), c) the current/wrong output and d) the desired/correct output; not many folks are going to take the time to step through the (posted) functions to figure out what's being fed to `sed`, what's coming out the other end of `sed`, let alone try to guess at what the desired output should be; K.I.S.S.

Comment: In the script you show below, you are calling sed once for each line of input.  Each time sed is invoked it makes a change because it only sees one line at a time, and that line is the last line.

Comment: Have you considered using Bash string manipulation instead? Try:    `filename="./bar/baz/foobar.txt"` then `echo "${filename/bar./Bar.}"` as an example...

Comment: I've updated my question, hopefully it is a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but to give you an insight for (GNU) `sed` flags.

`g` flag is for global, replace all matches.

```
$ echo barbarbar.etc | sed 's/bar/foo/g'
foofoofoo.etc

$ echo barbarbar.etc | sed 's/bar/foo/'
foobarbar.etc        

$ echo barbarbar.etc | sed 's/bar/foo/1'
foobarbar.etc

$ echo barbarbar.etc | sed 's/bar/foo/2'
barfoobar.etc

$ echo barbarbar.etc | sed 's/bar/foo/3'
barbarfoo.etc

$ echo barbarbar.etc | sed -E 's/bar(.etc)$/foo\1/'
barbarfoo.etc
```

`$` here is the anchor for the line end, not needed for the input above but for another input it will only match instance at the line end..

```
$ echo barbarbar.etc bar.etc| sed -E 's/bar(.etc)$/foo\1/'
barbarbar.etc foo.etc
```